# How do {{}} double curly brackets work in dplyr?

Tags: r, tidyverse, curly-braces, rlang

I saw Hadley's talk at [RConf](https://rstudio.com/resources/rstudioconf-2020/state-of-the-tidyverse/) and he mentioned using double brackets for calling variables in tidy evals.

I searched Google but I couldn't find anything talking about when to use them.

What's the use case for double brackets in dplyr?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`{{}}` (curly-curly) have lot of applications. It is called as meta-programming and is used for writing functions. For example, consider this example :

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(new_mpg = mean(mpg))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
#    cyl new_mpg
#  <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     4    26.7
#2     6    19.7
#3     8    15.1
```

Now if you want to write this as a function passing unquoted variables (not a string), you can use `{{}}` as :

```
my_fun <- function(data, group_col, col, new_col) {
  data %>%
    group_by({{group_col}}) %>%
    summarise({{new_col}} := mean({{col}}))
}

mtcars %>% my_fun(cyl, mpg, new_mpg)

#    cyl new_mpg
#  <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     4    26.7
#2     6    19.7
#3     8    15.1
```

Notice that you are passing all the variables without quotes and the group-column (`cyl`), the column which is being aggregated (`mpg`), the name of new column (`new_mpg`) are all dynamic. This would just be one use-case of it.

To learn more refer to:

- [Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)
- [rlang 0.4.0: curly-curly](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/)

Comment: Ronak, so the {{}} is used to replace the enquo() and !! operators? i.e. does curly-curly performs both quote and unquote simultaneously ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It performs both the operations together.

Comment: How would this work if what is being enclosed in {{}} is a group of variables (e.g. in group_by)  rather than just one?

Comment: Hi. What is the purpose of using ':=' here rather than '='?

Comment: This is explained [here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html#tidy-dots). Basically the left hand side of `=` can't be an expression so you need to use `:=` instead.

Comment: Is there a way to take advantage of this in ggplot2?  It doesn't seem to work in an `aes` statement.

Comment: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/dev/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html#using-aes-and-vars-in-a-package-function