# How to remove rows Inf from a specific column in a dataframe using Tidyverse in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, infinity

I have a dataframe and I want to remove rows with Inf values present in a selected column. I'm looking for a solution using tidyverse as I want to include it into my tidyverse pipes.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3, NA), b = c(5, Inf, 8, 8), c = c(9, 10, Inf, 11), d = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
```

I want to remove rows having Inf values in column `c`. The result would be:

```
df2 <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, NA), b = c(5, Inf, 8), c = c(9, 10, 11), d = c('a', 'b', 'd'))
```

I wish there was a function something like `drop_inf()`, similar to `drop_na()`.

EDIT: The column name is passed as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `is.finite`

```
df %>%
  filter(is.finite(c))

   a   b  c d
1  1   5  9 a
2  2 Inf 10 b
3 NA   8 11 d
```

If you want to have a dynamic column, you can use `{{ }}`:

```
my_fun <- function(df, filter_col){
  df %>%
  filter(is.finite({{filter_col}}))
}

my_fun(df, b)
my_fun(df, c)
```

This way you can work dynamically with `my_fun` like with other `dplyr` verbs.
For example:

```
df %>% select(a:c) %>% my_fun(c)
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64065003/how-do-double-curly-brackets-work-in-dplyr).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the column name is passed as a variable.

Comment: Sounds great and reasonable. But for some reason it doesn't work for me :( 

```variable <- 'CPC'```
In the data there is a column CPC.

```model_per_day <- function (account, campaign_type, variable, forecast_period) {
  data_per_day <- data %>%  
    filter(!is.infinite({{variable}})) )``` It doesn't throw any error but also doesn't remove the Inf's.

Comment: does the code work for the example you have provided?
You definitely have to provide  the data  you are using (i.e. `data`) as the first input to your function.

Comment: library('dplyr')
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3, NA), b = c(5, Inf, 8, 8), CPC = c(9, 10, Inf, 11), d = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
filter_col <- 'CPC'
filter_infs <- function(df, filter_col){
  df %>%
    filter(is.finite({{filter_col}}))
}

# This works - but it has the column name passed, which I don't want
df %>% filter_infs(CPC)
# And this doesn't work - while it has the column name passed as a variable. It filters out all the rows.
df %>% filter_infs(filter_col)

Comment: Sorry that it is all pasted in one line.. I don't know how to make Enters here...

Comment: it does not work because you are writing `filter_infs(df, 'CPC')`.
You should write of `filter_infs(df, CPC)` instead (do not use `''`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228212/discussion-between-ilona-and-cettt).