Replace specific symbols in a function in R
I have many functions that are intended to be used on a dataframe. For example:
BaseSquareFunction <- function(DataTable) {
  DataTable %>% 
    mutate(ValSquared = ValBase^2)
}

Is there a way to take that function and generate a new function where I've specified symbols to be replaced with new symbols? Something like this
NewFunction <- functionSymbolRename(BaseSquareFunction, ValBase_Case1 = ValBase)

where NewFunction would be equivalent to this function below?
EquivalentFunction <- function(DataTable) {
  DataTable %>% 
    mutate(ValSquared = ValBase_Case1^2)
}

I'd need the function generator to run on "symbols" (not sure if that's the right terminology) rather than a simple string replacement, as there may be cases where a name to be changed is a substring of a name that I don't want to change.
Ideally, I'd want NewFunction to print out exactly the same in the console as EquivalentFunction.

EDIT - I ended up accepting the functionSymbolRename implementation from MrFlick. However like MrFlick and others suggested, this is generally not a good idea. For example, you may end up overriding factors that were intended to be constants, and receive nonsense results
BaseSquareAdjFunction <- function(DataTable) {
  AdjFactor <- 100
  DataTable %>% 
    mutate(ValSquared = (Factor / AdjFactor)^2)
}

BaseSquareAdjFunction2 <- functionSymbolRename(BaseSquareFunction, AdjFactor = Factor)

BaseSquareAdjFunction2 would always generate 1's for ValSquared (assuming the input data has a non-NA numeric column AdjFactor).
That said, I'm accepting MrFlick's answer because of this specific situation of needing to work with and support what I'll call inflexible code. Like to the all-too-common task of adding features to poorly written legacy code, sometimes the only way to work with existing bad code in a timely manner is to create new bad code.

https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64065192/6851825

I can see how I'd generate brand new functions with that code. However, I've got a growing list of functions from users not familiar with any kind of non-standard-evaluation, and I need to generate modified functions based on those user functions

There might be a good way to to this but it seems fraught, and likely to create naming clashes that are hard to notice and fix. I suspect the best option is to rewrite those functions.

You could pull off such a functionSymbolRename function with
functionSymbolRename <- function(fun, ...) {
  tx <- list2env(as.list(match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...))
  body(fun) <- do.call("substitute", c(list(body(fun), tx)))
  fun
}

You just need to swap the order of the renames. It needs to be old=new. So you can run
NewFunction <- functionSymbolRename(BaseSquareFunction, ValBase = ValBase_Case1)
NewFunction
# function (DataTable)  
# {
#     DataTable %>% mutate(ValSquared = ValBase_Case1^2)
# }
dd <- data.frame(ValBase_Case1 = 1:5)
NewFunction(dd)
#   ValBase_Case1 ValSquared
# 1             1          1
# 2             2          4
# 3             3          9
# 4             4         16
# 5             5         25

This is still a fragile operation and doesn't really handle nested scopes and is not guaranteed to return a valid function. It's certainly not how people new to R should expect things to work.

It's generally not advisable to re-write the body of a function. It's more common in R to write a generator closure that can capture the variable parts of the function. For example
library(dplyr)

BaseSquareBuilder <- function(variable) {
  function(DataTable)
    DataTable %>% 
      mutate(ValSquared = {{variable}}^2)
}

This is a function that returns a new function. And then you use that function like this
NewFunction <- BaseSquareBuilder(ValBase_Case1)

Which we can test using
dd <- data.frame(
  ValBase_Case1 = 1:5
)
NewFunction(dd)

#   ValBase_Case1 ValSquared
# 1             1          1
# 2             2          4
# 3             3          9
# 4             4         16
# 5             5         25


I understand the case not to modify the body of a function itself. If I were working with R developers, I would take your approach. However, I have a team of historically excel developers trying to move a research process from spreadsheets to R. They need to be able to create and edit dozens (or hundreds) functions without any kind of non-standard-evaluation, and in turn I need to be able to modify all those functions. I'm aware this is an unusual case, and I'll need to do something to warn or stop if there are name clashes.

I do not advise this, since it will break unexpectedly and annoyingly, but you could overwrite columns dynamically to match the original function's needs:
BaseSquareFunction <- function(data) {
  data %>% 
    mutate(mpg = mpg^2)
}

BaseSquareFunction(mtcars)

                        mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4            441.00   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag        441.00   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710           519.84   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive       457.96   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout    349.69   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant              327.61   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
...

Then our new function dynamically replaces the data from the column we specify from the original function with the one we have chosen.
NewFunction <- function(data, col, replace_col) {
  data |>
    mutate(mytemp = {{replace_col}},
           {{replace_col}} := {{col}}) |>
    BaseSquareFunction() |>
    mutate({{col}} := {{replace_col}},
           {{replace_col}} := mytemp) |>
    select(-mytemp)
}

NewFunction(mtcars, cyl, mpg)


                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0  36 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0  36 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8  16 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4  36 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7  64 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant             18.1  36 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
...

This is bad code, but it does what you describe.
What this achieves is that now I have used the machinery of the BaseSquareFunction and applied it to a dynamic variable of my choice. In this kludgy implementation, I temporarily saved the old variable (mpg) to a new one (mytemp), then overwrote the old variable (mpg) with the one I want to select (cyl), then ran the function, and finally put the output into the column I selected (cyl) and put the original values of the old variable (mpg) back. But this level of bookkeeping is a clear code smell that we are messing with fire, and that a safer approach would be to rewrite the code.

Thanks. This is similar to a solution I'd come up with rename_with, but I can't seem to print it well (which is important for downstream error handling). (and yes, it is bad code. I'm still trying to figure out how to navigate supporting code from non-R developers))
